# npm start is not working in cmd and it is showing error as shown in image?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

This image contains details about the error when I am typing `npm-start`
[image: Image 1]

I have created a react-app using create-react-app. I have created another app using the same but when I type `npm-start`, it displays an error and `localhost:3000` stops working.

Comment: Can you add your package.json?

Comment: can you share the code of `events.js` file?

Comment: Do you have a file named events.js? If so, check line 174 for an error. I am seeing that in the image you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Missing npm package 
Use the cmd to install npm package ***npm install***

Check the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) here

Comment: I have tried it but again it is generating the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can follow these steps.

First, reinstall node_modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i //(rm -rf will only work if you have macOS for windows you need to delete node_modules manually)//
```

Then, start the project:

```
npm start
```

or

```
yarn start
```

Answer (score 0):

This error solved by few easier simple steps. That steps are

1. Go to your setting
2. Open your environment variable screen
3. Delete ComSpec variable completely and click ok
4. Uninstall your NodeJS
5. Reinstall your nodejs setup,

Finally it will be work